# Forecasting - Review Volume & Average Rating

Tags: forecasting, exponential-smoothing

I just want to confirm -

- our review volume has an upward trend but no seasonality. I can use holt's exponential smoothing. Right?
- for average ratings, no trend, and no seasonality. simple exponential smoothing?

Are there any other factors I should consider? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to both your bullet points.

"Any other factors": I would strongly recommend not using your own gut feeling in choosing a model, but to use an established forecasting package. In R, there are the free `forecast` and `fable` packages, both the gold standard in general forecasting. They of course also include exponential smoothing, in a more sophisticated state space framework. I also very much recommend [this free open textbook on forecasting](https://otexts.com/fpp3/), which was written by the authors of the R packages and serves as a wonderful complement to it.

Comment: thank you for your help!